proguard-rules for flutter plugin
I am unable to find documentation or any info on how to add proguard-rules.pro for a Flutter plugin. In a Flutter plugin, we don't have an app folder with a build.gradle file as we do in standard Flutter applications. I've been looking into how to achieve this but haven't found relevant information.
Any guidance on adding ProGuard rules in a Flutter plugin would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!
